Bounds on $\ell_1$ Norm in a Semidefinite Programming Problem
Consider the following SDP problem
\begin{equation}\label{P}\tag{P}
\begin{array}{cl}
\displaystyle\min_{x  \in \mathbb{R}^n,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} } & f(x) \\
\text{s.t.} & \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |\gamma_{ij}| \leq s,
\\
& \operatorname{tr}(\gamma) \leq 1,
\\
& \gamma - xx^\top \succeq 0,
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $s$ is a positive integer such that $s \leq n$, and $f$ is a convex function.
Observation:
Numerically, in optimal solution I see $\|x^*\|_1 \leq \sqrt{s}$.
Question:
For a feasible (optimal) solution$(x, \gamma)$, is the inequality $\|x\|_1 \leq \sqrt{s}$ valid?
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights.

Yes, consider $0\leq v^T(\gamma-xx^T)v$ for the vector $v=\mathrm{sign}(x)$.
